# Docker : publish port automatically with exact port number match

Tags: docker

I have this line in my `Dockerfile`:

```
EXPOSE 80
```

When I start my docker, I need to call `docker run -p 80:80 ...`

Ain't there an option to auto-publish every exposed port with the same port-number? I thought at first `-P` would do, but it actually matches the port to randomly selected ones.

This would be much handier than having to set `-p 80:80` and if the docker is configured to work with this parameter there is no reason to make the port numbers a parameters of `docker run`!

Comment: What if you had two images that wanted to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available as a feature.

You would need to wrap your docker run in a script [like this one](https://gist.github.com/tjmehta/33c87502956cb4cc56ee) (javascript) from [Tejesh Mehta](https://github.com/tjmehta):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

# Usage: docker run [..opts] `publish-static <image>:<tag>`

'use strict'

const execSync = require('child_process').execSync
const image = process.argv[2]
const inspect = JSON.parse(
  execSync('docker inspect ' + image).toString()
)
const ports = Object.keys(inspect[0].ContainerConfig.ExposedPorts)
let out = ports.reduce(function (str, p, i) {
  const port = p.split('/')[0]
  str += `-p=${port}:${port} `
  return str
}, '')

out += image

process.stdout.write(out)
process.exit()
```